# Which game system was the computer game HeroQuest based on?

Tags: product-identification

If I remember correctly, the computer game *HeroQuest* was based on rules from a tabletop RPG. Does anyone know which RPG's rules it was based on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was based on the classic Games Workshop / MB board game **[Hero Quest](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22192/hero-quest-advanced-quest)**.  (This was one of the better GW releases of the era.)  GW released an Advanced version which came closer to roleplay; it allowed for a GM and some ability development.  Still clearly a board game though.

Comment: A useful video review of what makes Hero Quest so good is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cx8sl2uC46A

Comment: I played the board game back in the day. It was more or less a tabletop RPG played *as* a board game, with relatively fewer rules and less DM fiat, since there were only a limited number of things a player was allowed to attempt. I think there were less than 10 spells total in the game that one could learn, and maybe half a dozen weapons.

Answer (score 13):

The HeroQuest computer game is an implementation of the GW/Milton Bradley board game, [Hero Quest](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/699/heroquest).

It draws heavily from the shared tropes of the Warhammer line of games, including [Warhammer Fantasy Battle](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4192/warhammer-fantasy-battle) and especially [Warhammer FRP](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/275/warhammer-fantasy-roleplay-1st-edition). It shares some minor mechanical similarities with WFRP, but is not actually the same system.

There also was an [Advanced HeroQuest](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1758/advanced-heroquest). It used a similar ruleset and compatible components, but was more involved.

The whole HeroQuest system is out of print.

There is a [HeroQuest RPG](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/2664/heroquest-1st-edition), but it's unrelated to the board game, being instead related to [RuneQuest](http://rpggeek.com/rpgfamily/970/runequest). It is currently in print in a 2nd edition, it's first edition being the revision of the slightly older version called [Hero Wars](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/1653/hero-wars-1st-edition).